# What does pipe character do in vim command mode? (for example, :vimgrep /pattern/ file | another_cmd)

Tags: linux, vim, vi

What does pipe character do in vim command mode?

For example, `:vimgrep /pattern/ file | copen`

Does it act like a pipe in Linux Command Line? Contents of `vimgrep` gets piped to `copen`?

Or does it separate commands like `;` in Command Line?

Comment: [`:h :bar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#:bar)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<kbd>|</kbd> is used to execute more than one command at a time.

In your example:

```
:vimgrep /pattern/ file | copen
```

This finds for the *pattern* in the specified *file* and then opens a window to show current list of occurrence of *pattern*.

The second command (and subsequent commands) are only executed if the prior command succeeds.

Comment: How does the first command transfer its data to second command?

Comment: It doesn't, that's not the point - it's not like the unix pipe, it's just running multiple commands on a single line. `vimgrep` does what it does and stores the result in the quickfix list. `copen` simply opens a window to show you the quickfix list. There is no transfer occurring in this command at all.

Comment: What's the help page for this?

Answer (score 6):

To OP's question: the latter.

This is actually a *vi* feature, not *vim*-specific, used to separate multiple commands.  It was answered before here:

- [What does `<Bar>` mean?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/what-does-bar-mean)
- [Learning the Vi and Vim Editors](https://books.google.com/books?id=Eb8J3BONVxAC&pg=PA468&lpg=PA468&dq=vi%20vertical%20bar&source=bl&ots=_0AXNVKZjl&sig=X6LzHQ9BtrwH9YpVI1yj1bgLyTM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCWoVChMImqa--veqyAIVyBo-Ch1MwAy_#v=onepage&q=vi%20vertical%20bar&f=false), "special meaning as a separator of multiple ex commands".

Comment: Is `|` an Ex command? How does the first command transfer its data to second command if those are independent commands?

Comment: As [@Dan Lowe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2449905/dan-lowe) pointed out, there is no transfer ("|" can mean different things, e.g., in regular expressions).