# How to use regex in vim to replace with an incrementing number variable

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I have a file which content like this:

```
id      phone   name
x'1234' 12345   jack
x'4567' 45678   Jojo
x'7890'  89456  Dio
x'4591'  34872  joseph
```

and i want to parse it into like this:

```
id  phone   name
1   12345   jack
2   45678   Jojo
3    89456  Dio
4    34872  joseph
```

I know basic regular expression could replace all id to any string
like this:

```
:%s/x'\(\w\+\)'/1/g
```

and it will become:

```
id  phone   name
1   12345   jack
1   45678   Jojo
1    89456  Dio
1    34872  joseph
```

How to replace id to an increment variable ?

Comment: Are you asking about vi or vim?

Comment: yes, i wanna change id to an increment number

Comment: That was not a yes/no question.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383607/4400820

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mind that **you can use an expression as the replacement string in the substitute command (`:s`)**. When the replacement string starts with `\=` it is evaluated as an expression.

Here, **one possible solution** is

```
:let i=1 | g/^x'\d\+'/s//\=i/ | let i=i+1
```

It finds all occurrences (one per line) of the `^x'\d\+'` pattern and replaces it with the value if `i` that is incremented each time the match is found. As has been [noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756503/how-to-use-regex-to-replace-string-to-variable-at-vi-vim/57756772?noredirect=1#comment101956450_57756772), the `|` is a part of the `g` replacing "code", as ["`|`  is used to execute more than one command at a time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943945/what-does-pipe-character-do-in-vim-command-mode-for-example-vimgrep-pattern).

**Another solution** is using the `line()` command (taking into account that your file has a header top line, so you should actually subtract `1` from the value returned with `line()`):

```
%s/^x'\d\+'/\=line('.')-1/
```

The **`^x'\d\+'` regex** matches

- `^` - start of a line
- `x'` - `x'` string
- `\d\+` - 1+ digits
- `'` - a `'` char.

There are other interesting *"increment number in regex"* examples at the [*Using an expression in substitute command*](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_an_expression_in_substitute_command) page:

> - Number all the lines in a file (insert line number followed by a tab):
>
>   ```
>   :%s/^/\=line('.')."\t"/
>   ```
> - Number a range of lines (from line 10 to line 20):
>
>   ```
>   :10,20s/^/\=line('.')."\t"/
>   ```
> - Number a range of lines sequentially starting from 1:
>
>   ```
>   :let counter=0|10,20g//let counter=counter+1|s/^/\=counter."\t"
>   ```
> - Number all the paragraphs in range starting from 1 (assuming the paragraphs are separated by one or more blank lines):
>
>   ```
>   :let counter=0|1,20g/^$\n^\s*[^\s]/let counter=counter+1|+1s/^/\=counter."\t"
>   ```
>
>   Note: The above command does not work for the first paragraph in the file if there is no blank line above it.

Comment: This is a very nice answer. But the part of it that's really interesting is that `| let i=i+1` is part of the `g//` command, so executed for each of those lines. Visually, it doesn't look like that, at a first sight. Explaining that part would improve this answer.

Comment: ohh, Thank you for your instruction and advice

Answer (score 8):

## one-shot

You can declare a variable as the other answer does, or:

```
:%s/^x'\([^']*\)'/\=line('.')-1/
```

Replace the last `1` by the line number of your header (id, phone, name) line if it doesn't sit in line 1.

## two steps

You can get followings just by replacing `1` into `0` in your codes

```
id  phone   name
0   12345   jack
0   45678   Jojo
0    89456  Dio
0    34872  joseph
```

Then you can move your cursor to the first id `0`, then press:

`ctrl-v` `G` `g` `ctrl-a`

It will turn the `0`s into a sequence from `1`

- `ctrl-v`: column mode
- `G` : select the 1st col till the last line.
- `g+ctrl-a`: add

Comment: it is interesting

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use use `awk`, `column`, & Vim's filter command.

```
:%!gawk 'NR>1 {$1=++i} 1' | column -t
```

Explanation:

- `:%!{cmd}` will "filter" the range, `%` (whole file), through command `{cmd}`
- `gawk '..'` will run an awk one-liner
- `NR>1 {..}` will run a "block" for record number greater than 1 (skips header)
- `$1=++i` will set the first field to variable `i` (pre-incremented)
- `1` is short of `{print}` which will print out the row
- `{cmd1} | {cmd2}` will pipe the output from command, `{cmd1}`, to the input of command `{cmd2}`
- `column -t` will pretty print tabular looking data

Answer (score 1):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) has (among many others) a `:Renumber` command for this; it simplifies the typical solution with `:substitute` and a *replacement expression*:

```
:%Renumber/^x'\d\+'/
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice answers, one trick I use to enumerate large protobuf files:

First search/replace your target with a unique string like %%%%, then use the following:
:let i=1 | g/%%%%/s//\=i/ | let i = i+1

e.g., to replace
[ProtoMember()]
[ProtoMember()]
[ProtoMember()]
with:
[ProtoMember(1)]
[ProtoMember(2)]
[ProtoMember(3)]

First make all into [ProtoMember(%%%%)]

:% s/Member()/Member(%%%%)/g

then use

:let i=1 | g/%%%%/s//\=i/ | let i = i+1